# Time space graphic with QT

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Do you know a quick and easy way to create a time space graphic like this one with Qt with a list/vector of point objects with a start and an end time, I dont know where to start

[image]:

.
Thank you!

Comment: How about this: http://doc.qt.io/QtCharts/qtcharts-linechart-example.html ?

Comment: do you think that I will be able to code a select on each line from one point to the other with this? each line in tne graph reprersents an object, lets say a trip from place A at time a to place B at time b and I need to be able to select it and get inside to view its details.

Comment: I am not 100% sure that you can do it, I have never used the QtChart class but the documentation looks promising, I see that QtCharts is built using QGraphicsView and QGraphicsItems which are graphics selectable objects, so I think it's worth trying.

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know . Thanks !